# Why does strikethrough get removed from a task when hovering over it?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I made a simple To-Do List Web App using Vue JS, and styled it using Bootstrap. When I add a task and mark it done, I add a class to it to strike it through. But when hovering my mouse over the task, the strikethrough gets removed. Why is this happening?

Here is the link to the code,
https://codepen.io/Nik96/pen/GzJxeP

```
<sample code to ignore>
    Because StackOverflow wouldn't let me post the question otherwise
</sample code to ignore>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because the following property is set on li element(Can be default).

```
list-group-item:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is removing your property **text-decoration: line-through**

You can use  **text-decoration: line-through !important** for temporary so that your property would not be overwritten.

Updated codepen link below

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJpRqN